# Database can't be imported error Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

So I've created a working database and am attempting to insert records into it however as far as I'm aware the data is not being inserted. The following is my connection string:

```
connect.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;" +            
     "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\LoginData.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

As well as this, I have the following code for insertions which throws zero exceptions:

```
try {
            using (SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Logins] values (@Username, @Password, @Email, @First_Name, @Last_Name)", connect))
            {
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", u1.Username);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", u1.Password);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", u1.EmailAddress);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("First_Name", u1.FirstName);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("Last_Name", u1.LastName);
                connect.Close();

            }

        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        }
```

When I attempt to refresh the data I get the following error:
"The database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an incompatible database"

The version of Visual Studio I am using is 2015 and I have SQL Server 2014 installed locally.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you test your connection?

Comment: The code your showing doesn't do anything. It only sets up a SqlCommand. You need to execute it before anything will happen.

Comment: When refreshing you get the error. Which means you can see the database and read the data, and the exception happens when you try to refresh?

Comment: I didn't realise I had taken out the execute statement when I posted that, there is one though. I have tested the connection and it succeeded. I can see the database but nothing is added and the exception appears when I hit the refresh button.